# Block select on a Linux console?

Tags: linux, terminal, console, mouse

Is there any Linux console (konsole, gnome-terminal, etc.) that allows selecting text in a block mode, like you can in a Windows cmd.exe window, using Mark and drawing a rectangle?

Comment: In case anybody is wondering, on Windows it is alt + drag.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging the left mouse button.

Comment: Thanks! Using Linux for so many years and it's the first time I needed this :)

Comment: FYI - Option-Command will do this on a Mac (at least on Terminal and iTerm2)

Comment: Works with gnome-terminal :D

Comment: @Cakemox Thank god someone added info on how to perform block selection on mac!!! :D

Comment: Works in gnome-terminal in tmux as well with shift-ctrl-alt

Comment: just `ctrl` worked for me

Comment: Ctrl + Shift in Tmux under any libvte terminal (gnome-terminal/mate-terminal/etc) works for me.

Comment: Works on `xfce4-terminal` too!!

Comment: The left `Ctrl`-`Alt` combination works for me, not the right one.

Comment: This is still relevant in 2023. THANK YOU!